# Can't compile OpenCV 3.1 on Raspberry PI: Missing videoio.h, videodev.h,

Tags: opencv, raspbian-jessie

All,
I've followed these instructions:
[installing OpenCV 3.0 on raspberry pi b+](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27232/installing-opencv-3-0-on-raspberry-pi-b)

and these:
http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/26/how-to-install-opencv-3-on-raspbian-jessie/#comment-389260

and neither work, because I keep getting the following fatal errors.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/opencv-3.1.0/build $ cat /home/pi/opencv-3.1.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log | grep fatal
/home/pi/opencv-3.1.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:28: fatal error: linux/videodev.h: No such file or directory
/home/pi/opencv-3.1.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:25: fatal error: sys/videoio.h: No such file or directory
/home/pi/opencv-3.1.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:29: fatal error: ffmpeg/avformat.h: No such file or directory
```

I've tried restarting from scratch with a new image of Jessie twice now, and I've scoured the internet and I keep turning up empty handed. Any guidance would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't like virtual environments like the one Adrian always work with. If you would like to try out my [cheat sheet](https://github.com/Tes3awy/OpenCV-3.1.0-Compiling-on-Raspberry-Pi-2-). I don't use virtualenv and it works well on RPI 2 Model B. Hope I helped. Don't forget to fork me on GitHub. To try out my cheat sheet you first have to enter the build directory and execute `sudo make clean`

Comment: Again everybody is replying about the `linux/videodev.h` but why none is taking about the `sys/videoio.h`

Answer (score 2):

You need the `libv4l` library. You can install it by running `sudo apt-get install libv4l-dev`.

In addition, you may also need additional libraries to compile OpenCV properly. Running the command `sudo apt-get build-dep opencv` should get you everything you need.

Comment: @EnemyBagJones `libv4l-dev`. Not just `libv4l` lol. My answer says: "You can install it by running `sudo apt-get install libv4l-dev`"

Comment: I already had this library installed .. so this didn't unfortunately fix the problem, so something else is amiss

Answer (score 1):

To fix the first line, you should install the `libv4l-dev` package and manually link header files:

```
sudo apt-get install libv4l-dev
cd /usr/include/linux/
sudo ln -s ../libv4l1-videodev.h videodev.h
```

About the last line:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/include/ffmpeg && \
sudo ln -sf /usr/include/libavcodec/*.h /usr/include/ffmpeg && \
sudo ln -sf /usr/include/libavformat/*.h /usr/include/ffmpeg && \
sudo ln -sf /usr/include/libswscale/*.h /usr/include/ffmpeg && \
```

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include some explanation here, e.g. what do these commands do? Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here.

Answer (score 1):

Scouring internet for possible solution of the exact same issue I faced landed me here and no solution specified worked. What I did notice though is:-

1. Not all steps described in the pyimagesearch blog were followed - missed some steps - checked one by one though not sure this was the root cause.
2. OpenCV 3.1.0 has a bug and you need to set `INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF`. This info is available as an update in the pyimagesearch blog of

   26-10-2015:-
   "Update (3 January 2016): In order to build OpenCV 3.1.0 , you need to set -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF  (rather than ON ) in the cmake  command. There is a bug in the OpenCV v3.1.0 CMake build script that can cause errors if you leave this switch on. Once you set this switch to off, CMake should run without a problem"

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same errors too - then I saw, it was a **typo**...
If in the cmake command, the path to the extra modules is wrong, you run into these errors. Therefore be sure, that the directory of the opencv_contrib files is allright, for v. 3.1.0, it should be:

-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.1.0/modules

(and not ...~/opencv_contrib-3.0.0/... what you get when you copy/paste the instructions you mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

A in my case, probably as silly as you get an example to compile/build from older versions.

Check your references are right.

```
$ cd ~/opencv-3.4.0/
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON  -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.4.0/modules -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```